# How to get next page in silenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on selenium in python, I want to scrape all pages, but I am in trouble:
Here is the element I want to click:
[image]

I am using the folloing code:

```
link=driver.find_element_by_link_text ('2')
link.click()
```

But it give click on another element

Deos there exist another way to get next page?

Comment: can you tell me what is the `xpath` for this elem?

Comment: AFAIK, `find_element_by_link_text` searches `a` tags with the specific text so I doubt that would work for your case as you want to click on the `li` tags. Try [`find_element_by_xpath`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath).

Comment: @Pygirl //*[@id="pagination_wrapper"]/ul/li[2]

Comment: In my project I created a list for the pagination thing and stored xpath: https://github.com/ninjakx/CPCB/blob/87332cbe332a681423cf049977f042b96a460600/cpcb.py#L202. This will give you an idea.

Comment: using beautiful soup get how many pages are there. then you can use `//*[@id="pagination_wrapper"]/ul/li[<counter_page_num>]` increment the counter page num on each iteration until it reaches the total number of pages. I hope you got my point.

Comment: @Pygirl Yes, I tried this one , but it return that:

Comment: @Pygirl 'ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (662, 3590) '

Comment: Oh no! :( https://www.testim.io/blog/selenium-element-is-not-clickable-at-point/ Can you debug what's causing it? I guess you should introduce some time delay may be that's is taking few seconds to get generated by js. My first suggestion would be introduce some delay using time module. It's always a good idea to use some delay when you are dealing with script rendered elements.

Comment: Actually my second code is "link = WebDriverWait(last_pages, 5,ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,'//*[@id="pagination_wrapper"]/ul/li[2]')))"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230333/discussion-between-pygirl-and-shorena-tevzadze).

Comment: @Pygirl but it gives me the same error

Comment: `link = driver.find_element_by_xpath( '//*[@id="pagination_wrapper"]/ul/li[2]')`        
  `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link) `                                               this code works if run `link.click()`   it gives me the error `Message: element click intercepted: Element <li value="...">2</li> is not clickable at point (662, 584). Other element would receive the click: <div class="close_cookie_alert">...</div>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, sees like your element what you're trying to click overlapped by another one, so you need to wait for its becoming being clickable or other one disappear:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,//div[@id="pagination_wrapper"]//li[@value="1"])))
```

or

```
WebDriverWait(driver, LONG_TIMEOUT
        ).until_not(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='close_cookie_alert']")))
```

Here's like you can find all of yours elements:

```
link1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="pagination_wrapper"]//li[@value="1"]')

link2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="pagination_wrapper"]//li[@class="2"]')

link3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="pagination_wrapper"]//li[contains(text(),"text of the third element")]')
```

if usual click doesn't work, try to use click via javascript, like that:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link1)
```

or, just move to the next page with:

```
 driver.get('new_page')
```

Comment: It's already solved in the comment. How your answer is different than the comment one?

Comment: @Pygirl i've not noticed that the question was solved. does my answer disturb you?